# Latest post class in Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to limit css changes to the latest post page?

For example, I often use the page-id class to limit changes to that particular page.

```
.page-id-166 p { font-size: 26px; }
```

I searched the body and found nothing.
Is there any class like .page-latest-post?

Comment: not with pure CSS. You will need some PHP in order to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

You may add the following code to your `functions.php` file. This will add the 'latest-post' class to the body tag classes.

[Docs on `wp_get_recent_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/)

[Docs on the `body_class` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/)

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'mysite_body_classes' );
function mysite_body_classes( $classes ) {
    global $post;

    // change 'post' to whatever your post type is
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) { 
        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'post_status' => 'publish' // only look for published posts
        );

        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

        if ( ! empty( $recent_posts ) && $recent_posts[0]['ID'] === $post->ID ) {
            // change your class name to whatever you need it
            $classes[] = 'latest-post'; 
        }
    }
    
    return $classes;
}
```